# Trim double quotes in json received from mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using JSON and MongoDb for the first time.. So when i insert into Mongodb and retrieve the result I get the value as

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4e67eb04b475e7c236a0c82c"} , "database" : "mkyongDB" , "table" : "hosting" , "detail" : { "records" : 99 , "index" : "vps_index1" , "active" : "true"}}
```

When i exrtact the value of "database" i get the value as

> "mykongDB"

With double quotes displayed. 
And i have to remove the double quotes every time i extract the value from JSON. Is this the way JSON or MongoDB behaves or am i missing something..

My code to retrieve value using mongo driver in java

```
public DBObject find(String key,String value){
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(key,value);
    return collection.findOne(query);
}
```

The way i extract value from JSON is

```
    DBObject dboject = client.find("database", "mkyongDB");
    System.out.println(dboject);
    JsonNode node =  mapper.readTree(dboject.toString());
    JsonNode innerNode = ((ObjectNode)node).get("_id");
    System.out.println(innerNode);
     String objectId = innerNode.get("$oid").toString();
```

I am using jackson JSON parser

whats wrong ? I dont want to handle removing the double quotes every time i extract the value.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't look like the double quotes are being stored in the Mongo field as part of the string.  If they were, the JSON output would look something like this:

```
{ "database" : "\"mkyongDB\"" }
```

So, it's probably a result of how the JSON is being parsed.

Does the Java driver deserialise the JSON into the DBObject class? Maybe you access the field by calling something like `dboject.get("database")` and casting the result to a string?

It's also worth checking out the [Java Language Center](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Language+Center), there are loads of links to tutorials, libraries and frameworks for POJO mapping that might make life easier.

Comment: you are correct. dbobject.get() works fine . I was wrongly assuming to use the JSON parser to get the details ..Thanks