# MongoDB Java Driver is returning quoted strings

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm developing an application on Java using MongoDB for persistence stuff.

We have the following POJO:

```
 private class DocumentType{
   private ObjectId oid;
   private String shortName;
   private String printingName;
   private String description;
   //Tax Code is a list of 3-digit numeric codes (must match pattern \\d{3}).
   private List<String> taxCodes;
 }
```

We have created a custom CODEC for this class, which simply performs the following encoding:

```
   writer.writeObjectId("_id", value.getOid());
   //... writes every property value, if value is null invokes writer.writeNull("property")
   wrirter.writeName("taxCodes");
   writer.writeStartArray();
   taxCodes.forEach(writer::writeString);
   writer.writeEndArray();
```

And when decoding, after checking the reader BsonType and name, invoke `reader.readString`.

Everything works fine, after inserting a lot of test values, the result in the MongoShell can be verified and is as expected, the taxCodes are shown correctly (ie: "taxCodes" : ["001", "003", "145", "325"]).

Then, when querying the collection, the decode implementation do the following:

```
    //some funny stuff to make sure the reader state is not end of document.
    //some funny stuff to know which field name we are reading.
    //if readName result is taxCodes, we must read the array of tax codes:
    reader.readStartArray();
    while(reader.readBsonType() == BsonType.STRING)
        item.getTaxCodes().add(reader.readString());
    reader.readEndArray();
   //funny stuff to read other fields...
```

The expected result would be that now, taxCodes would contain the string values, in such way that invoking `taxCodes.forEach(System.out::printLn);` should result in the output:

```
   001
   003
   145
   325
```

But it doesn't, it result in the output:

```
   "001"
   "003"
   "145"
   "325"
```

It's not an issue with my IDE, or my system console, I've prepared a UnitTest which prints the taxCodes if I set them manually and works fine. So, my problem is that reader.readString doesn't return 001, it returns "001", but why? It only happens with that field, why don't happens with the name field, or the description field? What would you do to fix this?
My test mongodb server version is 4.4.0, and my driver dependencies are:

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-reactivestreams -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-reactivestreams</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/bson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reactivestreams/reactive-streams -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341324/trim-double-quotes-in-json-received-from-mongodb) looks relevant.

Comment: thanks bkis. I didn't realized my question was duplicated. Now I rely on string codec, so instead of reader.readString, now I use context.decodeWithChildContext(REGISTRY.get(String.class), reader) and that solved the quotes issue. I guess that StringCodec checks some stuff when reading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trim double quotes in json received from mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341324/trim-double-quotes-in-json-received-from-mongodb)

Comment: not directly, but it gave me a hint on what to change on my codecs to solve the problem.